# Unable to render one child component before another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, rendering, conditional-rendering

I am working on a React application which renders two large tables in separate components under one parent component. I have been trying to render the first table before the second one, but I am not able to achieve this. Here is the code sample:

```
class Parent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = ({
    loading: true,
    table1Data: [],
    table2Data: [],
    loadTable2: false
  })
}

componentDidMount() {
  axios.get('url').then ((response) => {
    this.setState({
      loading: false,
      table1Data: response.data.users,
      table2Data: response.data.activity
    })
  });
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if (prevState.loading != this.state.loading) {
    this.setState({ loadTable2: true });
  }
}

render() {
  if(this.state.loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Table1 data={table1Data} />
      {this.state.loadTable2 && <Table2 data={table2Data} />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

}

There are some computations done in both `<Table1/>` and `<Table2/>`. With the code above, both the tables are rendered together, producing a delay before Table1 is rendered.
Could someone please help me achieve this functionality? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Implement componentDidUpdate in Table1 component. Pass a callback from Parent to Table1. Use the callback to set state to loadTable2=true

Comment: Tried that, but still getting the same problem.